# What is causing the 'Unknown base64_encode filter' error in Twig when trying to add base64 encode/decode filter in Drupal 9?

Tags: drupal-9, twig-filter

I want to add base64 encode decode filter in twig. But it's showing Unknown "base64_encode" filter. in Twig\ExpressionParser->getFilterNodeClass()

I have tried with below filter but nothing works.

```
{% set youtube_id = content.field_youtube_embed_code|render|striptags|trim %}
{{ youtube_id|base64_encode }}
```

```
<p>{{ 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dapibus.'|base64_encode }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filter is a part of Symfony2 but unfortunately not a part of Drupal Twig package.
If you want to use it the simpliest way is to create your own module with something like this (*it's just an untested mockup, please review before implementing*)

```
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class TwigExtensions extends AbstractExtension {

  public function getFilters() {
    $filters = [];
    $filters [] = new \Twig\TwigFilter('base64_encode', function (string $encode) {
      return base64_encode($encode);
    });
    return $filters;
  }
}
```

alternatively `Twig Tweak` module [PHP filter](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#php) might do what you want.